# Limit Trigonometric arctan

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone help me find this limit :

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^3 + \sin(2x) - 2\sin(x)}{\arctan(x^3) - \arctan(x)^3}$$

Comment: Can you draw conclusions from your last two questions about how to go about evaluating this limit?

Comment: how should $\tan^{-1}(x)^3$ be interpreted?

Comment: must be interpreted like that (arctan(x))^3

Comment: just appply taylor series to all the functions and neglect higher order terms

Comment: @Faker123 Hint: What do you get when you series expand the numerator and denominator around $x=0$?

Comment: i didn't understand :/

Comment: @Faker123 You can use l'Hopital rule to the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

$\arctan x = x - \dfrac{1}{3}x^3 + \dfrac{1}{5}x^5 + O(x^6)$

$(\arctan x)^3 = x^3 - x^5 + O(x^6)$

$2\sin x = 2x - \dfrac{1}{3} x^3 + \dfrac{1}{60}x^5 + O(x^6)$

$\sin(2x) = 4x - \dfrac{8}{3} x^3 + \dfrac{8}{15}x^5 + O(x^6)$

Then

\begin{equation}
   \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3 + \sin(2x) - 2\sin(x)}{\arctan(x^3) - \arctan(x)^3}
   = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{4}x^5+ O(x^6)}{x^5 + O(x^6)}
   = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{4}+ O(x)}{1 + O(x)}
   = \frac{1}{4}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

We have

\begin{align}
  \sin(x)
  &= x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120}(1 + \epsilon(x)),\\
  \frac{1}{1+X^2}
  &= 1 - x^2(1 + \epsilon(x)),\\
  \arctan(X)
  &= x - \frac{x^3}{3}(1 + \epsilon(x)).
\end{align}

So, your limit is

\begin{equation}
  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{x^5(1 + \epsilon(x))}{4}}{x^5(1 + \epsilon(x))} 
  = \frac{1}{4}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Good , but can you explain more how u did for sin(x) = X - (x^3)/6 +...            I have no idea about that

Comment: lol Faker, all these answers are based on my comment.

Comment: yeah , i can see thati just have no idea about Taylor Series :p

Comment: @Anonymous Taylor expansion is well known.

Comment: i think so , but im not expert at math , im just a student in terminal

Comment: @Faker123 If you don't know about Taylor series (/polynomials), now's the time to learn.  The limits you're trying to evaluate are complicated enough that Taylor expansions really are your best method.  If you've never seen them before, try [KhanAcademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/series-calc) as an introduction.

Comment: There is no other way to fin this limit without Taylor Series :p ?

Comment: @Faker123 I imagine there's some clever way to bound this and use the squeeze theorem, but Taylor expansions are going to be the *easiest* way.